# Type '' is not known on line 3 in source list

Tags: apt

When I type in `sudo apt-get update`, I get this error:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
N: Ignoring file 'getdeb.list.bck' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Type '' is not known on line 3 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/libdvdcss.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move `getdeb.list.bck` file to another location.

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list.bck ~/Desktop
```

And then remove `''` from the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/libdvdcss.list` in the line 3.

You can do this through `sudo -H nautilus` command. Finally run `sudo apt-get update` to update all repositories.

Comment: Weird Can't find it on my desktop..

Comment: I moved it but I can't find it on my Desktop..

Comment: run `ls ~/Desktop` command.

Comment: Nope I found a file in the Home Folder called Desktop and when i open it,it opens gedit and it says:deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu precise-getdeb apps

Comment: try the next commands. Don't woory about the moved file.

Comment: So when i type in sudo nautilus I get this error :@:Nautilus-Share-Message: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: 'net usershare' returned error 255: net usershare: cannot open usershare directory /var/lib/samba/usershares. Error No such file or directory
Please ask your system administrator to enable user sharing.

Comment: I got it working Thanks man I love you (no homo) :D